# Trap a function call?

Tags: c++, function

Is there a way to trap a function call in C++. Like a process may be calling setLocale even though. I want to find whether is there any call to it or not ?

Comment: This seems to be platform-specific, please clarify

Comment: As an alternative: use a profiler or if really needed, check the profiler code to see how the profiler gets its information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can understand from you statement. It is fairly easy to do with any debugger. Run you code on `gdb` add a `breakpoint` on the first line of your function. When this breakpoint hits see the `backtrace` to know how this function was called.

Comment: No the thing is my code does not have any call to that function. What I am suspecting is whether 3rd party libraries of whose code I don't have are using that function or not. So, how can I find that ?

Comment: you can find that by following what i said in my answer. I hope you have the 3 libraries with you and you bind those libraries to create an executable which you have to run with `gdb`. In that case my solution would work.

Comment: If these libraries are dll then ?